# Cannot make a pack layout in d3? selectAll not working?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, nan, selectall

I am relatively new to coding and very new to d3. I am currently trying to use d3 with json to make a pack layout representing current presidential candidates and how many times they have talked about a certain issue during the feedback.

I wanted to start small so I made some dummy data in a .json file, it is below:

```
{
 "name": "John Doe",
 "party": "democratic",
 "issues": [
  { "issue":"issue1", "value": 25 },
  { "issue":"issue2", "value": 10 },
  { "issue":"issue3", "value": 50 },
  { "issue":"issue4", "value": 40 },
  { "issue":"issue5", "value": 5 }
 ]
}
```

I want to display bubbles with "issue" as the label and "value" as the circle radius, ending up with five different sized circles on my canvas. Below is my index.html file:

```
var width = 800, height = 600;

var canvas = d3.select("body").append("svg")
 .attr("width", width)
 .attr("height", height)
 .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(50, 50)");

var pack = d3.layout.pack()
 .size([width, height - 50])
 .padding(10);

d3.json("fakedata.json", function (data) {

 var nodes = pack.nodes(data);

 var node = canvas.selectAll(".node")
  .data(nodes)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
   .attr("class", "node")
   .attr("transform", function (d) {
     return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
   });

 node.append("circle")
  .attr("r", function (d) { return d.r; })
  .attr("fill", "steelblue")
  .attr("opacity", 0.25)
  .attr("stroke", "#ADADAD")
  .attr("stroke-width", "2");

 node.append("text")
  .text(function (d) {
    return d.children ? "" : d.issue;
 });
});
```

I keep getting the error below and I think it is because node is not being set correctly.

```
 Error: Invalid value for <g> attribute transform="translate(NaN,NaN)"
 Error: Invalid value for <circle> attribute r="NaN"
```

Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON you are passing is

```
{
 "name": "John Doe",
 "party": "democratic",
 "issues": [
  { "issue":"issue1", "value": 25 },
  { "issue":"issue2", "value": 10 },
  { "issue":"issue3", "value": 50 },
  { "issue":"issue4", "value": 40 },
  { "issue":"issue5", "value": 5 }
 ]
}
```

It should have been like below note the key name **children** instead of **issues**

```
{
 "name": "John Doe",
 "party": "democratic",
 "children": [
  { "issue":"issue1", "value": 25 },
  { "issue":"issue2", "value": 10 },
  { "issue":"issue3", "value": 50 },
  { "issue":"issue4", "value": 40 },
  { "issue":"issue5", "value": 5 }
 ]
}
```

Working code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/12gjj6dy/).

Answer (score 1):

The answer is a bit late, but in case you don't want to change your data structure and you want to keep the `issues` property, you can explicitly tell D3 to use the `issues` property for children data using the `children()` call:

```
var pack = d3.layout.pack()
   .size([width, height - 50])
   .children(function (d) { return d.issues; })
   .padding(10);
```